# R/Shiny histogram class as reactive

Tags: r, shiny

R allows to save histograms as "histogram" class objects:

h <- hist(x,plot=FALSE)

and several values can be recovered from "h". For instance
"h$mids", "h$counts" etc ...

Now, I need to use this in a Shiny script but I can't find
how to save "h" as a reactive variable. Do you know how to 
do that?

I tried: h <- reactive({hist(x,breaks=y,plot=FALSE)})

but it doesn't work.

The following is my script.

Thanks

Juan

---

```
library(shiny)

InputParameters <- function(u) {

sidebarPanel("Input parameters"
,numericInput("N","Number",1000,min=100,max=10000,step=100,width=NULL)
,numericInput("mc","Mean",0.22,min=0.02,max=0.5,step=0.02,width=NULL)
,numericInput("sc","Sttdev",0.57,min=0.4,max=0.8,step=0.01,width=NULL)
,numericInput("logmstep","Bin",0.2,min=0.1,max=0.5,step=0.1,width=NULL)
,width=2)

}

ui <- fluidPage(

sidebarLayout(

        InputParameters("A"),            

        mainPanel(                    
                navbarPage("IMF2CMD"
                ,tabPanel("System-IMF"
                ,plotOutput("plot1",width="100%",height="700px",click=NULL,
                        dblclick=NULL,hover=NULL,hoverDelay=NULL,
                        hoverDelayType=NULL,brush=NULL,clickId=NULL,hoverId=NULL,
                        inline=FALSE)
         )

      ) 
    ) 
  ) 
) 


server <- function(input,output,session) {

logmc        <- reactive( { log(input$mc,10) } )
logm         <- reactive( { rnorm(input$N,logmc(),input$sc) } )
breakslogM   <- reactive( { breakslogM <- seq(-3,2,input$logmstep) } )

output$plot1 <- renderPlot( { hist(logm(),breaks=breakslogM(),plot=TRUE) })

h           <- reactive( { hist(logm(),breaks=breakslogM(),plot=FALSE) } )

}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: I had no problem using the `h` variable by creating a second output: `output$hist_data <- renderPrint({ h() })`

Comment: Thanks Ryan for your suggestion. It works. Now the variables can be recovered by: counts <- reactive( { h()$counts } )

observe({ print(counts()) })

Answer (score 0):

It works with your `h <- reactive( { hist(logm(),breaks=breakslogM(),plot=FALSE) } )`, and then `output$plot1 <- renderPlot( { plot(h()) })`